# QtCreator Static Analyzer is failing on yocto "gnu/stubs-soft.h" is missing

Tags: c++, qt-creator, yocto, clang-static-analyzer

I created a kit on QtCreator from a yocto project... the SDK in installed with populate_sdk.
The toolchain is using GCC 7.3.0 with hard float.

I can build without any problem from QtCreator but when I try to run the static analyzer I got an error: `gnu/stubs-soft.h` is not existing.

Looking for that file indeed it doesn't but `gnu/stubs-hard.h` does.

A fast workaround was to duplicate this file and rename it. This workaround is working fine, but I am wondering to know if there's a better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem. I found a work around by adding "-mfloat-abi=hard" to the compiler flags in my CMake file:

```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} \
      -mfloat-abi=hard)
```

I target gets actually compile with that flag. For some reason QtCreator does not pick up this flag from the Yocto-environment.

Comment: hmmm maybe because that flag is token taken from the enviorment... I need to check it

Comment: Dunno if is better change the toolchain file or duplicate the folder... both aren't good